# How do you send ether using truffle/ether-pudding?

Tags: javascript, truffle, ether-pudding

How do you do a sendTransaction to simply send ether from one account to another in [ether-pudding](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ether-pudding)?

In web3 I would do this:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: a, to: b, value: 100 })
```

I would like the promisey goodness of ether-pudding though.

Comment: I looked at the ether-pudding source and it appears to not be possible currently. synchronizeFunction needs to be applied to a normal sendTransaction. I am going to work on a pull request.

Comment: Update: @tcoulter suggested that this shouldn't go in Pudding as it is a contract abstraction library, not a general purpose web3 wrapper. I guess I will look into porting synchronizeFunction to a separate lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4035/383  Ether-pudding is focused on working with Contracts.

web3 is the main library for interacting with Ethereum from javascript.