# How do you get the balance of an account using truffle/ether-pudding?

Tags: javascript, truffle, ether-pudding

Is there an [ether-pudding](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ether-pudding) way to get the balance of a contract/account, or should I just use `web3.eth.getBalance(account)`?

Comment: I'm still having a hard time with this. Something recently changed with the latest truffle release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless something has changed in ether-pudding, it is primarily focused on wrapping/simplifying contract code while also adding javascript promises to deal with asynchronous calls.  So I do not believe it has a simpler call to get the balance.

Short answer: use the web3 call you mention.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't exist in `truffle-contract`. Here's a quick way to wrap `web3` calls to make them use promises.

```
const promisify = (inner) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    inner((err, res) => {
      if (err) { reject(err) }
      resolve(res);
    })
  );

const getBalance = (account, at) =>
  promisify(cb => web3.eth.getBalance(account, at, cb));

// use getBalance
const bigNumberBalance = await getBalance('0xabcdef');
console.log(bigNumberBalance.toString());
```

You can use this `promisify` helper to wrap any function which accepts a callback param and handles errors the same way as `web3`. Here's another example of using it:

```
const getTransaction = (hash) =>
  promisify(cb => web3.eth.getTransaction(hash, cb));

// use getTransaction
const transaction = await getTransaction('0xcaff');
```